# qcss не работает font-size

Tags: qt5

Есть метка `QLabel` Для неё прописаны HTML правила.

```
QLabel *display = new QLabel("0");
    display->setStyleSheet("background-color: #FFF8DC; color: #7D0000; border: 1px solid gray; border-radius: 6px; font-size: 1.5 em;");
    display->setAlignment(Qt::AlignRight | Qt::AlignCenter);
```

Работает всё, кроме font-size. Как решить проблему?

Comment: только `pt` и `px` поддерживаются

Comment: [The font size. In this version of Qt, only pt and px metrics are supported](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html)

Comment: Пасиб, понял, а то полез ковырять уже далеко.